# java.lang.NullPointerException: null while assigning current date to variable

Tags: java, date, parsing, groovy, nullpointerexception

In my `ISData` class i have create below method:

```
public static final DateFormat IN_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

and now in my `TSTIMP` class i am trying to assign the current sys date value in the `IN_DATE_FORMAT` format to variable `import_date` which is Date datatype. But dont know how to do that. I want to parse this date into String as i need to later on store this in database table. Currently i am getting error as `java.lang.NullPointerException: null`

```
data.import_date = InstrumentMasterData.IN_DATE_FORMAT.parse(<need to provide sysdate> as String)
```

Below i tried for variable `effective_date` which is also `Date` datatype and it works fine:

```
data.effective_date = allocDate != null ? InstrumentMasterData.IN_DATE_FORMAT.parse(allocDate as String) : null
```

Also i have `data.fund_quote_date` variable which is also Date datatype and it should always be null. How can i assign null value to this varaible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i am trying to assign the current sys date value in the IN_DATE_FORMAT
> format to variable import_date which is Date datatype. But dont know
> how to do that.

You can use [`DateFormat#format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)) to get the system date string in the `IN_DATE_FORMAT` format e.g.

```
data.import_date = InstrumentMasterData.IN_DATE_FORMAT.parse(InstrumentMasterData.IN_DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date()) as String)
```

However, this is unnecessarily formatting a `Date` object using `IN_DATE_FORMAT` and then parsing the same formatted string back to a `Date` object. Instead of this, you can simply do:

```
data.import_date = new Date();
```

> Also i have `data.fund_quote_date` variable which is also Date datatype
> and it should always be null. How can i assign null value to this
> varaible ?

Simply, assign `null` to it:

```
data.fund_quote_date = null;
```

**Note:** If it is possible for you, **stop** using the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat`. Switch to the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.time` date-time API and the corresponding formatting API (`java.time.format`). Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: thanks its working with the second approach data.import_date = new Date(); and not the one...its complaining for IN_DATE_FORMAT.format where IN_DATE_FORMAT is not recognized

Comment: data.import_date = new Date() with this approach the perfromance is bit more time consuming...

Comment: @Symonds - In your case, it will be `InstrumentMasterData.IN_DATE_FORMAT` instead of just `IN_DATE_FORMAT`. I've updated the same in the answer as well.

Comment: do you mean in the question where i have created value for variable data.effective_date its not necessary to do that also ? but how can i handle null date value in this case ?

Comment: You should do it simply as `data.effective_date = allocDate;`. If `allocDate` is `null`, the variable `data.effective_date` will be assigned `null` and if  `allocDate` has some value, the same will be assigned to `data.effective_date`. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: i have create one question do you have any idea about this thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473326/remove-column-from-csv-in-groovy

Comment: @Symonds - I've responded there. I'm not sure if that helps.