# remove column from csv in groovy/java

Tags: java, csv, groovy, insert, cell

I am using Select query to retrieve the data from database and generate CSV which is working fine.

In my `FData` class i have below method where i am doing formating for cell value in csv. I have column `ATYPE` in my select query which i dont want to write in csv or may be after writing just clear the complete column `ATYPE` field from csv so that it cant be shown.

Is there way i can do that in below method to do this logic?

```
private static void IFile(File output, Sql sql, String query, List<String> columns) {
        output.withWriter { writer ->            
            writer.writeLine(columns.join(CSV_SEPARATOR))           
            sql.eachRow(query) { rec ->
                try {
                    writer.writeLine(columns.collect { columnName ->
                        def cell = rec[columnName]
                        // cell data processing for CSV output...If cell is empty then replace with "" else do the other formating
                        if (cell != null) {                                
                            if (cell.properties["class"] == Timestamp.class)
                                return IData.OUT_DATE_FORMAT.format(cell)                              
                            
                        }
                        else {
                            return ""
                        }
                        return cell
                    }.join(CSV_SEPARATOR))
                }                 }
            sql.close()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code given below, the exact syntax may be wrong (I've just a beginner-level knowledge in groovy) but you will get the idea of how to solve it:

1. Filter the column names before joining i.e.

   ```
   writer.writeLine(columns.findAll({ it != 'ATYPE'}).join(CSV_SEPARATOR))
   ```
2. Filter the data before writing i.e.

   ```
    writer.writeLine(columns.findAll({ it != 'ATYPE'}).collect { columnName ->
        //...
    }
   ```

Comment: thanks..will try it but just want to know in this it != 'ATYPE' where does the 'it' object comes from ?

Comment: yes it works :) but can you please tell me what does this 'it' object means ?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54902509/what-is-the-groovy-it) and [this](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) and let me know if you want to know anything else about `it`.